# IPC concurrency at pipe data exchange

Tags: c, pipe, ipc, semaphore

I am trying with the following piece of code to have multiple exchanges of data between processes with multiple pipes. I am using semaphores to avoid concurrency errors.

A child process that never dies handles the `storeSomeData()` and other processes communicate with this one to store and retrieve data.

An abstract model of the code is the following:

```
#define _Size_OF_IPCB                
struct sembuf up = {0, 1, 0};
struct sembuf down = {0, -1, 0};
int mySemaphore;                      //Initialization of the semaphore

int keyFD[2];
int valFD[2];
int retFD[2]; //pipe file descriptors

int main(){
    pipe(keyFD);
    pipe(valFD); //assignments of FDs
    pipe(retFD);
    mySemaphore=semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, 0666 | IPC_CREAT); //semaphore init

    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid==0) //process that never dies
    {
        while(1){
            read(keyFD[0], ipcBUFFER, _Size_OF_IPCB); //blocks at read
            if(ipcBuffer[0]=='f') //foo
            {
                write(retFD[1], someData(), strlen(someData())); //writes back
            }
            else if(ipcBuffer[0]=='b') //bar
            {
                read(valFD[0], ipcBUFFER2, _Size_OF_IPCB); //read again
                storeSomeData(); //store the data
            }
        }
    }
    else //father
    {
        semctl(mySemaphore, 0, SETVAL, 1); //unlocking semaphore
        while(1){ 
             someBlockingOnInputFunction(); //father is waiting a user input
             pit_t pidChild;
             pidChild=fork();
             if(pidChild==0) //child will handle this input
             {
                  bufferDataCreation(); //input handling
                  semop(mySemaphore, &down, 1); // locking semaphore
                  if(buffer[0]=='f') //foo
                  {
                      write(keyFD[1], buffer, strlen(buffer)); //writes
                      read(retFD[0], readBuffer, _Size_OF_IPCB); //reads
                  }
                  else if(buffer[0]=='b') //bar
                  {
                      write(keyFD[1], buffer, strlen(buffer)); //writes
                      write(valFD[1], buffer, strlen(buffer)); //writes
                  }
                  semop(mySemaphore, &up, 1); //unlocking semaphore
                  close(keyFD[0]);
                  close(keyFD[1]);
                  close(valFD[0]);
                  close(valFD[1]);
                  close(retFD[0]);
                  close(retFD[1]);
                  exit(1);
             }
         }
    }
```

So the father keeps getting user input, passes the 'job' into another child, and this child communicates with the first one created, to exchange or store some data, regarding the user input.

When the user input comes piece by piece everything runs ok. If user input starts coming one after another with a greater speed (using a script to achieve that), the above procedure hangs. Either the 'process that never dies' waits for a read or write or the other way around with a child process that processes the input and tries to read or write on a pipe.

I am not asking for code corrections. Is something in the logic of the above model wrong? I am not familiar with pipes and i can't realize what's the problem.

Thank you for any kind of help!